# Moving mutltiple documents to a folder in dropbox on a pc

Tags: file-management, dropbox

How can I move multiple documents in my dropbox to folders in my dropbox at one time?

Moving them one by one is too time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear.

Your question says "how can I move multiple documents in MY DROPBOX to folders IN MY DROPBOX at one time?"   Are you moving files/folders from one place in dropbox to another folder in dropbox?  Are you using the web interface or the client?

I suggest going and downloading the dropbox client.    This will install a folder in your My Documents folder called Dropbox.   This folder will sync any files/folders that you put into the Dropbox folder automatically with dropbox's servers.   You can easily manage multiple files/folders if you use the Dropbox client just like you would if you were using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Just login to dropbox.com and choose `upload`, then drag and drop the files. Nothing special about that...

[image]

Check that you do not use the "standard upload" - there you can only upload one file. Remember you need a more or less up-to-date browser (not Internet Explorer 8).

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides the other answers (installing the client and multiple file upload) you can move multiple files, that are in your Dropbox already, via the Dropbox web-interface itself.

Click one file (to the right of the filename). The whole line will become blue. Now hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key and select the other files. This way you can select multiple files. After that Click the `Move` at the top and choose your destination-folder.

[image: Dropbox Web-ui]